# Frequent Theme Switch Due to Cache

Tags: custom-theme, theme-fallback

I am using Magento 2.2.7 on a vps. I am using SM Market Theme. Due to Language problem of Theme support team, they are unable to understand the issue, thus I am not getting the solution.

In the admin section I have applied SM Market as my main theme. Due to cache or some unknown issue the home page theme is switched to SM Mobile Theme. To apply the main theme again, I have to run the php bin/magento c:c and c:f sometimes the indexer:reindex along with cache clean and flush command.

This is a frequent issue with the theme/store. The mobile theme has dummy content. And the home page looks like a mess.

I explained it many time to support but they always says, clear the cache and rebuild. I feel this is a temporary solution and required a dedicated person to check the home page and run the commands.

[image]

Please suggest a solution. All cron jobs are working fine and runs every 15 min. But cron job is not clearing any cache.

Home page after them page switch. 
[image]

for original page you can refer www.rbhomoeoshop.com

Thanks,
Niraj

Comment: what exactly is your question? how do you expect us to give support for a 3rd party (probably closed-source) extension

Comment: @PhilippSander my question is, why home page theme gets changed due to cache? Is it related to cache or theme? If you have any idea, Please guide so that I can ask specific query to theme developer. Hope its clear now. I have added one more image for reference.